# how can fire event after end loading nested html page (page in object )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i want hide object after html page end loading  not the man html tag 
this is my code

```
$('<div id="content" ><object data="../06.html"></div>').appendTo('section')
```

i try use `load` but return after div loading i don't want this

Comment: What is ``$('')``? What do you want exactly?

Comment: Explain better what you are talking about???

Comment: I need load external  html page to div and after it finished from loading hide another object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, you can start some action after the DOM is loaded. The content (e.g. images) isn't necessarily already there, but you can manipulate every DOM element after the DOM is ready. Use the following snippet for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //some code
});
```

If you want to wait until the page is fully loaded (e.g. also images), you can use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
   //some code
};
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide a `<div>` when your webpage is fully loaded:

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('div').fadeOut(); //or .hide()
});
```

To show a div when the page is fully loaded:

```
$(window).load(function (){
   $('div').fadeIn(); //or show()
});
```

If that's not what you're looking for, then please do explain more about your problem.

Comment: i don't need load for current page i want  access after the external page load